# How to assure java lost focus event handler finish its work before executing another event handler

Tags: java, swing

I am in the process of integrating voice recognition component with my existing application. In my application I have a JTree and JTextPane. I have written lost focus event handler for jtextpane and selection event handler for JTree. When the focus is in the jtextpane and then select a node in the jtree i can see that before the focus lost event handler, the selection event handler is executed. I have written ThreadPoolExecutor in the focus lost event handler and i add three jobs to ThreadPoolExecutor, i must assure before executing selection handler i should finish all the jobs in ThradPoolExecutor; for that i have use countdownlatch. I have read many similar post but i could not find how to assure focus lost is finished before executing selection event handler. Some post had asked to run the selection event handler code in invokeLater method. But it is not a solution for my problem because ThreadPoolExecutor executes its code in another thread. Below i have note down the sequence i want to execute my code

1. Add jobs to ThreadPoolExecutor in focus lost event handler
2. Block the UI thread and finish all the added jobs to the ThreadPoolExecutor in the lost focus event.
3. Execute the selection event handler.

Below is written code of my focus handler

```
public void focusLost(FocusEvent e)
  {

    if (ecaControl.isInitialized())
    {

      ecaControl.addStopRecordingJobToExecutor();

      ecaControl.addSaveJobToExecutor(this.currentMetaFileName != null ? this.currentMetaFileName : this.getName());

      ecaControl.addCloseJobToExecutor();

      co = new CountDownLatch(ecaControl.getExecutor().counter);
      ecaControl.getExecutor().setCountdownla(co);

      try
      {
        System.out.println("------- count before" + ecaControl.getExecutor().counter);
        co.await();

        ecaControl.getExecutor().setCountdownla(null);
      }
      catch (InterruptedException e1)
      {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
      }
      System.out.println("--------count after" + ecaControl.getExecutor().counter);
      try
      {
        System.out.println("The text is "
            + this.getStyledDocument().getText(0, getStyledDocument().getLength()));
      }
      catch (BadLocationException e1)
      {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
      }

    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the selection event only ever occurs in tandem with the `focusLost()` event, then you should call [`awaitTermination()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#awaitTermination%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) on the `ThreadPoolExecutor` and then call an `invokeLater()` method in the selection event.  If not, then the best solution would probably be an event dispatcher.  If you sent all events to an event dispatcher, it could coordinate whether or not the `JTree` needs to wait, execute any threads necessary, and then re-dispatch the events to the appropriate components at the appropriate time.